# "Equal Division of objects into groups" formula

Tags: combinatorics

My book says the number of ways to distribute to 2n objects equally among two groups where order is considered is $\frac{2n!}{(n!)^2}$ but I have a doubt

Let's take an example

No. Of objects= 4 $\{A, B, C, D\}$

Number of ways to distribute these four object into groups which contain two objects each
G1(_ *)               G2(* _)
Now let's make all possible groups

```
 **G1**             **G2**
    AB.  |   AC, AD, BC, BD, CD
    AC.  |   AB, AD, BC, BD, CD
    AD.  |   AB, AC, BC, BD, CD
    BC.  |   AB, AC, AD, BD, CD
    BD.  |   AB, AC, AD, BC, CD
    CD.  |   AB, AC, AD, BC, BD
```

So, the number of ways to distribute these objects into two groups each having two objects when order of groups is considered is   6×5= 30 ways

As,  $(AB, AC) (AB, AD) (AB, BC) (AB, BD) (AB, CD)$ 5 groups from each row above

**But according to the formula it is **
4!/(2!×2!)= 6 ways

Please explain how this formula is true.

Comment: Use mathjax to render the maths, you have a tuto here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Why can't G2 contain AB in the first line?

Comment: @JMP bcoz when we place A and B in 1st group they are already taken and we can't put  them in 2nd group

Comment: Then you can't have AC in the second group, can you ?

Comment: @Fabien here i tried to show when I take A and B in 1st group then those in G2 are all other options of groups that can be in group 2

Comment: @NikhilPant but if you put A and B in G1, you can't put one of them in G2. Or do you mean you want to split the pairs of elements in two groups ?
What do you mean by "where order is considered" ? The order in a group ? Between the two groups ? Both ?

Comment: @Fabien thanks man I got it

Comment: In the first line if $G1$ is $AB$ then $G2$ can't have $A$ or $B$.  It can only have $C$ and $D$.  And as the order of groups matter but not the order within the groups do not there is only one possible $G2$.  So there are $6\times 1 = 6$ ways.

Comment: @fleablood thanks i got it

Answer (score 1):

There are $(2n)!$ ways to line up the objects, because each way to do it is a permutation of these objects. The $n$ first objects in the row form group 1 and the $n$ last objects form group 2. There are $n! n!$ copies of the same distribution in two groups in this because each group can be permutated. Hence the result
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}
\end{equation}
Note that if you don't differentiate the groups (by their number) you need to divide this result by 2.